# Request for Tag cleanup

Tags: support, tags

I've recently created both the [multi-part](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-part) and [multi-part-films](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-part-films) tags. One of these is clearly redundant but I don't have permissions to delete it.

Can someone do the honours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are deleted automatically (after 24 hours, I think) when they don't have questions associated. So you shouldn't really worry about this. Wrong tags happen often enough and they don't need to be deleted manually, neither are users able to do this, I think (if moderators are even able to do it at all).

Comment: That being said, I'm not so sure we need either of those, but nevermind.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure when I made it - book adaptation may suffice. We'll see.